# Advice on use of survival vs logistic model

Tags: regression, logistic, survival, repeated-measures, splines

I have a longitudinal dataset from a medical registry where every subject has a certain medical condition. Periodically, each subject is checked for a specific outcome (yes, no) of interest. I have date for each outcome check up, as well as time since diagnosis of the original medical condition and several other explanatory variables.
I am confused about the differences between use of a survival e.g. cox model vs (pooled) logistic regression in this scenario. The goal is to assess risk factors for the outcome. I have read that logistic regression ignores the time information. However this would not be the case if we include time since dignosis of the original condition as an explanatory variable (e.g. smooth spline) in a logistic model. This "time" is equivalently time to check up (which can be a yes or no event).
Any help to organise my thoughts would be great!

Comment: Continuous time-to-event analysis using survival analysis methods are virtually identical to doing a pooled logistic regression on a weekly basis.  Yearly data will approximate that.  This is related to https://www.jstor.org/stable/2288857 by Efron.  Also take a look at Markov state transition models: https://hbiostat.org/proj/covid19.